# How to convert XML using XSLT and copy nodes along with attributes

Tags: xslt

I have a following XML which should get transformed to "Expected Output" (As mentioned below. But I am not sure why is node attribute (ABC) is not coming inside the xml tag but outside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Node ID="ABC">
<Name>Name-ABC</Name>
<Description>Desc-ABC</Description>
</Node>
</Root>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="Node">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ABC
Name-ABC
Desc-ABC
</Node>
```

Expected Output (Attribute should be inside), Also I do not need to copy any node which is not matching the templates I have created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="ABC"></Node>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the attributes of the `Node` element then add a template `<xsl:template match="Node/@*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>` or make sure you copy them with `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` inside the template of the `Node` element. It is not clear what you want to do with the child elements, if you don't want them copied or output at all then remove the `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` inside the template.

If you only know the name of the element you want to copy to the output then start your stylesheet with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Node"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then use the suggestions already made, that is

```
<xsl:template match="Node/@*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="Node"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>
```

or as an alternative to those two templates you can use a single template for `Node` doing

```
<xsl:template match="Node">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok Tried your suggestion. It looks like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="Node | @*">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet. The output is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Node xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/> which is not including attribute

Comment: I suggested to add a template with the match template `Node/@*`. You have not added a template but changed the match pattern and contents of the existing template.

Comment: ok, Tried doing that, the output is as expected <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Node/@*">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> but now my only issue is that extra tags information is also getting populated. For exampleif there is another node1 then XSL will fail :(

Comment: Suppose this is xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Node1>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <Date>2015-05-11</Date>
  </Node1>
  <Node ID="AA" ID1="1">
    <ID>AA</ID>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Description>Test 
</Description>
  </Node>
</Root>

Comment: If you don't want `Node1` to produce any output then add a template `<xsl:template match="Node1"/>`.

Comment: Yes that I agree, the only issue is I know only tags which I need and rest I have no clue about them

Comment: @user2397257, I have edited my answer with an additional template.